# SAS Proc NPAR1WAY wilcoxon exact test produce null P value?

Tags: sas, statistical-test

I have a campaign result where i have a test and holdout dataset where the variance is not normally distributed. I was trying to use Proc NPAR1WAY wilcoxon exact test to get the P value. For some reason all the output is properly populated, but the Exact Test portion is showing Null for all the fields. Not sure what else to check as all the value within the VAR is not null and the log is not showing any ERROR message.

```
PROC NPAR1WAY WILCOXON DATA = TEST1;
CLASS TEST_HOLDOUT_FLAG;
VAR VARIANCE;
EXACT WILCOXON;
RUN;
```

Result

```
Wilcoxon Two-Sample Test                    
Statistic (S)    3.18E+12                

Normal Approximation                    
Z    8.1747                
One-Sided Pr > Z    <.0001                
Two-Sided Pr > |Z|    <.0001                

t Approximation                    
One-Sided Pr > Z    <.0001                
Two-Sided Pr > |Z|    <.0001                

Exact Test                    
One-Sided Pr >= S    .                
Two-Sided Pr >= |S - Mean|    .                
Z includes a continuity correction of 0.5.                    

Kruskal-Wallis Test                    
Chi-Square    66.826                
DF    1                
Pr > Chi-Square    <.0001
```

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the data. Any chance you can share some of the data? Also did it not produce a table that says "scores for variable variance classified by variable test_holdout_flag?" - if yes, can you share those results also.

Comment: Why do you mention that the 'variance is not normally distributed'? I don't believe that's an assumption for ANOVA. How many observations do you have? I suspect it's a large amount which is why you may not get exact results. Does the log have any warning or notes? Post the log please.

Comment: A bit curious about your data as well. Is the test and holdout data paired?